# Creating an updater. Updating/downloading part

Tags: java, download, updates

I want to create an updater, but I am not sure how I want to do this part. I want that my updater checks for updates and then count all the updates it has to do, so like: You still need 3/5 updates. or something like that. I know have that it checks if there is an update available and if there is an update then it downloads that update directly and after that it checks for another update and downloads that, but I want it to check all updates and after that download them.
This is the Launcher class

```
package com;

import com.check.Checker;
import com.download.DownloadData.DownloadFiles;

public class Launcher {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        for (DownloadFiles df: DownloadFiles.values()) {

            String fileName = df.fileName;
            String URL = df.URL;

            switch(Checker.isLatest(fileName, URL)) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Downloading " + fileName + ".");
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Updating " + fileName + ".");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println(fileName + " is up to date.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and this is the isLatest method:

```
public static byte isLatest(String fileName, String downloadUrl) {
        if (!hasFile(fileName)) {
            System.out.println("[" + fileName + "]" + "There is no file yet.");
            return 0;
        }
        try {
            if (DigestUtils.md5Hex(new FileInputStream(Settings.saveDir)).equalsIgnoreCase(DigestUtils.md5Hex(new URL(downloadUrl).openStream()))) {
                    System.out.println("[" + fileName + "]" + "Your file is up to date.");
                return 2;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("[" + fileName + "]" + "Your file needs to be updated.");
        return 1;
    }
```

So my question is: How do I make the launcher do it in this order: check the updates. List the updates and after that download the updates.

Comment: I think you pressed "return" to early.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not entirely sure that I understood your question, but maybe you want to do sth like:

```
//in Launcher

EnumSet<DownloadFileS> filesToUpdate = checkForUpdates(DownloadFiles.values());

listFilesToUpdate(filesToUpdate);

downloadFiles(filesToUpdate);
```

Then in `checkForUpdates` you just create the list of files which have changed since last sync, in `listFilesToUpdate` you simply print them out and in `downloadFiles(filesToUpdate)` you download them. Basically you already have everything in your `isLatest` method - you just need to split it by responsibility.

**UPDATE**

```
public List<DownloadFiles> checkForUpdates(List<DownloadFiles> allFiles) {
    allFiles.stream()
        .filter(file -> !hasFile(file.getFilename()) || !fileUpToDate(file))
        .collect(toList())

private boolean isFileUpToDate(DownloadFiles file) {
    return DigestUtils.md5Hex(new FileInputStream(Settings.saveDir))
       .equalsIgnoreCase(DigestUtils.md5Hex(new URL(downloadUrl).openStream())));
```

**NEXT UPDATE**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<DownloadFiles> filesToUpdate = checkForUpdates(DownloadFiles.values());

  listFilesToUpdate(filesToUpdate);

  downloadFiles(filesToUpdate);
}

private static void downloadFiles(List<DownloadFiles> filesToUpdate) {
  filesToUpdate.stream()
      .forEach(file -> downloadFile(file));
}

private static void downloadFile(DownloadFiles file) {
  try {
    URL website = new URL(file.URL);
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file.filename);
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}

private static void listFilesToUpdate(List<DownloadFiles> filesToUpdate) {
  System.out.println("Following files will be updated");
  filesToUpdate.stream()
      .forEach(System.out::println);
}

public static List<DownloadFiles> checkForUpdates(DownloadFiles[] allFiles) {
  return Arrays.asList(allFiles).stream()
      .filter(file -> !hasFile(file.filename) || !isFileUpToDate(file))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static boolean isFileUpToDate(DownloadFiles file) {
  try (InputStream is = new URL(file.URL).openStream()) {
    return DigestUtils.md5Hex(new FileInputStream(Settings.saveDir))
        .equalsIgnoreCase(DigestUtils.md5Hex(is));
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Uhm, I am not sure that I understand your code. I have a code that checks for updates using md5hex. That code looks in the existing files to the md5hex and if it isn't corresponding, then it has to add them to a download list or something like that.

Comment: is it clearer now? I think that I don't entirely understand your question. Could you ask it briefly?

Comment: Can you explain what that code does? So I know how to implement it.

Comment: Please ask me a specific question becaus  I can't answer on it. This code does what you asked for :)

Comment: Okay, when I use this. I get some errors. I am missing the toList, checkForUpdates, listFilesToUpdate and downloadFiles methods.

Comment: Is is now what you've asked for?

Comment: This is what I want indeed, but it updates every file. When I run this program it downloads the newest files. Then I run them again and it starts downloading all files again.

Comment: Now I suddenly get: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Ruud\Desktop; (Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden)
 at com.check.Checker.isFileUpToDate(Checker.java:36)Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Ruud\Desktop; (Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden)
 at com.check.Checker.isFileUpToDate(Checker.java:33)
The system can't find the path specified. This worked before?
This is the line where the error is referring to: return DigestUtils.md5Hex(new FileInputStream(Settings.saveDir))

Comment: Dude, do you even know what do you want to achieve? I wrote code for you using the code you pasted in your question. If sth is wrong then ask a specific question... Don't ask anyone to do your job

Comment: I am asking how I would make my downloaded first check for updates and after that download the updates. I know how I would make it check and download over and over again, but not first checking and the downloading

Comment: maybe it would be good to create checksum on the server-side and at first download just checksum to check whether it's the same as the local one. If not then you should download the right file.

Comment: Okay, but I want to use 1 file and Dropbox if that is possible

Comment: So maybe you should consider using dropbox java api: https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/java ?

Comment: I will look that up, once I got my files back, because I got some virus :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure in terms of code but you would want to have the client connect to the server and check some method of what version of updates it is on. e.g. Client is on 1.0.3 and server is on 1.0.5 so x must need updating.
Then you would need to download/update the files and install them or whatever.

Finally you would need to update the version listing in the client and store it somewhere (text file?) so that the process can start from the current point next time.

[Can't comment. Sorry]

Comment: Okay, My updater downloads from dropbox. Is there another way of storing temporary information? Like in an array that contains the file name, download url and if it needs to deleted and then downloaded or only downloaded.

Comment: You could possibly store it in an array. But remember that data will have to be in the code or be re-written on every restart. Personally I would store the information in a text file that records version listings. Then just parse through the text file comparing differences

Comment: I am checking the differences in md5hex, which is different in every version of a file, right?

Comment: Yep that should be correct. You may need to generate the md5 checksum yourself though

Comment: what do you mean by: "You may need to generate the md5 checksum yourself though"

Comment: I'm just having a read of this: javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/how-to-generate-md5-checksum-for-files.html

(I've never used md5hex myself)

Comment: Okay, thank you for trying to help me. I'll wait for someone that knows a bit more from it.